# Как можно ограничить число показываемых строк в dropDown при потов Razor

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, razor

У меня есть dropDown и по дефолту в списке 20 записей, как я могу показывать только 10, а чтобы увидеть остальные пользователю нужно будет прокрутить скрол.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => selectedUsers, availableUsers, "Choose new admin", new { @class = "dropdowns", @style = "width:200px;"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => selectedUsers, availableUsers, "Choose new admin", new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", data_size = 11, data_width = "200px"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "yearList", 
    Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),  // <!-- TODO: bind with a real data
    new { 
        size = "10", 
        style = "width: 200px" 
    }
)
```